# Class not recognized by one team member

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, object, tfs

I am working on a project with a friend that requires us (and by that I mean we want to) use a dll.
We can point to and use all classes without problem but there is one specific class that throws a build error on his side only (I can run the code fine):

```
initMerge merge = new initMerge();
```

We have used this for all the other classes and they work fine, but this one just throws an error:

> The type or namespace name 'initMerge' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I have already added the appropriate using statement and reference  and made sure the class is public and the namespace correct and I cleaned and rebuilt the solution to no avail.

We are using TFS in VS 2012 Express and it has worked flawlessly so far

Comment: Can you post the exact code and the exact error?

Comment: Do you have a Constructor for the Class initMerge ?

Comment: Also I believe it should look like `initMerge merge = new initMerge(myClassName);`

Comment: that (my class name) was just a clarification probably should have kept it out, fixed

Comment: If all else fails, and you're not using a Source Control system (you should be), run a diff utility on both projects, and find out what the differences are.

Answer (score 3):

You probably forgot to add the **public** modifier to your class definition. Also do not use parenthesis to notate your code as it is confusing and is not valid C# code. Lastly, I would name your class InitMerge instead of initMerge to follow proper .NET naming conventions.

```
public class InitMerge
```

The only other possibility is that you did not reference your other project. Check the references under the project that is using it and make sure it includes the DLL

Answer (score 2):

The using statement does not make the namespace available to you, it allows you to utilize it directly without qualifying the it.  You have to add a reference in your project.

Comment: I have done that as well, only this class is throwing this error, none of the others that are in the same dll.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the external DLL to your project.

If you already have a reference, hover over the initMerge statement and click on the dropdown list of suggestions that VS provides for resolving the problem.

Comment: VS provides no such things, just points out the error.

Comment: @user1934886: it actually does provide this directly in the code (assuming your are using 2005 or later). This SO link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052116/can-you-enable-error-corrections-for-c-sharp-in-visual-studio) contains information about this feature and here is an excellent MSDN article that includes screenshots (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942823.aspx).